# .on(click) for layer groups in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I have three layer groups. How to use `.on (click)` for all layer groups without repeating the code? Do I really need to use `.on(click)` for each layer group? It seems to be unnecessary lots of code.

When using this below I only get the on click window for the last layer group (area_skrym) and no info for the first two. Script load the same data and use the same info when you click on the map, but I can not get it to work with below JavaScript code.

```
var area_size = new L.layerGroup();
var area_weight = new L.layerGroup();
var area_skrym = new L.layerGroup();

$.getJSON("/geojson/area_polyg.geojson", function(json) {

var vectorGrid_size =  L.vectorGrid.slicer(json, {
                  maxZoom: 20,
                  zIndex: 5,
                  rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,
                  vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                      sliced: function(properties, zoom){
                      var avl = properties.Total
                      if (avl <= 500){
                        return{
                      weight: 1,
                      color: 'white',
                      opacity: 0,
                      fill: true,
                      fillColor: '#4575b4',
                      stroke: true,
                      fillOpacity: 0.6
                      }
                      } else if (avl >= 500 && avl <= 1500){
                        return {
                      weight: 1,
                      color: 'white',
                      opacity: 0,
                      fill: true,
                      fillColor: '#91bfdb',
                      stroke: true,
                      fillOpacity: 0.6
                      }
                      } else if (avl >= 1501 && avl <= 3000){
                        return {
                      weight: 1,
                      color: 'white',
                      opacity: 0,
                      fill: true,
                      fillColor: '#e0f3f8',
                      stroke: true,
                      fillOpacity: 0.6
                      }
                      } else if (avl >= 3001 && avl <= 4500){
                        return {
                      weight: 1,
                      color: 'white',
                      opacity: 0,
                      fill: true,
                      fillColor: '#ffffbf',
                      stroke: true,
                      fillOpacity: 0.6
                      }
                      } else if (avl >= 4501 && avl <= 6000){
                        return {
                      weight: 1,
                      color: 'white',
                      opacity: 0,
                      fill: true,
                      fillColor: '#fee090',
                      stroke: true,
                      fillOpacity: 0.6
                      }
                      } else if (avl >= 6001 && avl <= 7500){
                        return {
                      weight: 1,
                      color: 'white',
                      opacity: 0,
                      fill: true,
                      fillColor: '#fc8d59',
                      stroke: true,
                      fillOpacity: 0.6
                      }
                      } else {
                      return {
                      weight: 1,
                      color: 'white',
                      opacity: 0,
                      fill: true,
                      fillColor: '#d73027',
                      stroke: true,
                      fillOpacity: 0.6
                      }
                    }
                     }},
                     interactive: true,
                   })

var vectorGrid_weight =  L.vectorGrid.slicer(json, {
                  maxZoom: 20,
                  zIndex: 5,
                  rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,
                  vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                      sliced: function(properties, zoom){
                      var gods = properties.1_gods
                      if (gods === 'Yes'){
                        return{
                      weight: 1,
                      color: '#e41a1c',
                      opacity: 1,
                      fill: true,
                      fillColor: '#e41a1c',
                      stroke: true,
                      fillOpacity: 0.6
                      }
                      } else {
                      return {
                      weight: 0,
                      color: 'white',
                      opacity: 0,
                      fill: false,
                      fillColor: '#ffffff',
                      stroke: false,
                      fillOpacity: 0
                      }
                    }
                     }},
                     interactive: true,
                   })

    var vectorGrid_skrym =  L.vectorGrid.slicer(json, {
                  maxZoom: 20,
                  zIndex: 5,
                  rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,
                  vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                      sliced: function(properties, zoom){
                      var skrym = properties.size
                      if (skrym === 'Yes'){
                        return{
                      weight: 1,
                      color: '#377eb8',
                      opacity: 1,
                      fill: true,
                      fillColor: '#377eb8',
                      stroke: true,
                      fillOpacity: 0.6
                      }
                      } else {
                      return {
                      weight: 0,
                      color: 'white',
                      opacity: 0,
                      fill: false,
                      fillColor: '#ffffff',
                      stroke: false,
                      fillOpacity: 0
                      }
                    }
                     }},
                     interactive: true,
                   })

 .on('click', function(e) {
  var properties = e.layer.properties;
  L.popup()
    .setContent(
      "<b>Size</b>: " + properties.size +
      "<br><b>Number</b>: " + properties.code +
      "<br><b>Name</b>: " + properties.name +
      "<br><b>Total</b>: " + properties.Total + '.pieces' + 
      "<br><a href='" + 'mailto:' + properties.email + "'>Contact email</a>" + 
      "<br><b>Date</b>: " + properties.date)
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .openOn(map);
                    })

vectorGrid_size.addTo(area_size)

vectorGrid_weight.addTo(area_weight)

vectorGrid_skrym.addTo(area_skrym)

            })
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few approaches to this. The most basic is to define an event handler and reuse that when defining events, e.g.:

```
function handleClickOnSomething(ev) {
  var properties = ev.target.properties;
  L.popup().setContent(properties.something).setLatLng(...).openOn(map);
}

vectorGrid_size.on('click', handleClickOnSomething);      
vectorGrid_weight.on('click', handleClickOnSomething);    
vectorGrid_skrym.on('click', handleClickOnSomething);
```

This kind of refactoring is applicable elsewhere - just look for places where defining a thing once and referencing it several times will make the code architecture simpler.

Another approach is to leverage Leaflet's `L.FeatureGroup`s. From the [Leaflet reference](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#featuregroup):

> Extended `LayerGroup` that makes it easier to do the same thing to all its member layers: [...] Events are propagated to the `FeatureGroup`, so if the group has an event handler, it will handle events from any of the layers. This includes mouse events and custom events.

So you can do something like:

```
var group = L.featureGroup();

vectorGrid_size.addTo(group);
vectorGrid_weight.addTo(group);
vectorGrid_skrym.addTo(group);

group.on('click', function(ev) { /* ... */ });

group.addTo(map);
```

Just be aware of the difference between `ev.target`, `ev.sourceTarget` and `ev.propagatedFrom` in that context - check the [Leaflet reference for details](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#event).

Comment: It worked but I needed to change "ev" to "e" like `e.layer.properties` and `function handleClickSomething(e) {` or I got an error that properties is not defined...