# .on("load") event for layer groups in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, group-layer, loading

I have used Leaflet's ImageOverlay to load various image layers onto a Leaflet map div (L.map).  The size of the layer files can vary greatly.  So some layers load very quickly while others can take a couple of seconds (and not every image layer file actually exists).

I would like to check whether all the layer files requested have been fully loaded before doing something else.  I can find out if each individual layer is fully loaded using .on("load", function() { ... }).

For example,

```
layer1 = L.imageOverlay(...);
layer2 = L.imageOverlay(...);
layer3 = L.imageOverlay(...);

layer1.on("load", function() {console.log("layer1 loaded")});
layer2.on("load", function() {console.log("layer2 loaded")});
layer3.on("load", function() {console.log("layer3 loaded")});
```

However, when I defined a LayerGroup,

```
var AllLayers = L.layerGroup([layer1, layer2, layer3]);
```

and then tried

```
AllLayers.on("load", function() {console.log("All layers loaded")});
```

I did not get "All layers loaded" in the console.

I came across a related question on the .on("click") event
[.on(click) for layer groups in leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317232/onclick-for-layer-groups-in-leaflet)

I tried to define a layer group using L.featureGroup

```
var AllLayers = L.featureGroup([layer1, layer2, layer3]);
```

However, it did not show "All layers loaded" in the console either when all the layers were loaded.

I don't know how I would go about trying the first method answered in the above article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way of doing this would be to count `load` events of individual layers and when count is equal to number of layers, it's done.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var nLayers = 0;
var nLayersLoaded = 0;

function setLoadEvent(layer) {
  nLayers++;
  layer.on("load", function() {
    nLayersLoaded++;
    if (nLayersLoaded == nLayers) {
      console.log("all layers loaded");
    }
  });
}

setLoadEvent(layer1);
setLoadEvent(layer2);
setLoadEvent(layer3);
```

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks, TomazicM.  I thought this should work.  But when I tried this, I immediately got "all layers loaded" displayed in the console without waiting for each individual layer to get fully loaded.

Comment: I forgot to initialize `nLayers` to 0, corrected now. But even with that, order of doing things is important. First image layers have to be created, but not added to the map, then load events have to be created and only after that image layers added to the map.

Comment: So if I add these 3 lines below your codes:

layer1.on("load", function() {console.log("layer1 loaded")});
layer2.on("load", function() {console.log("layer2 loaded")});
layer3.on("load", function() {console.log("layer3 loaded")});

The console shows "all layers loaded" first when not all layers were actually loaded.  Then, "layer1 loaded", "layer2 loaded", "layer3 loaded".  I recognize that this is related to asynchronous javascripting.  But I am new to this and I'm not sure how it should be tackled.

Comment: I tested code from the answer, and it works as it's supposed to. You must be doing something wrong in your code.

Comment: It turned out that I needed to let `var nLayers = nLayersLoaded + nLayers` in order to achieve the desired result.  It took me hours to investigate the reason.  I use Leaflet's `setUrl` to update or reload the URL of the image already loaded with ImageOverlay.  But each time I use `setUrl`, nLayersLoaded is increased by 1.  I don't know the internal workings of `setUrl` to understand why this would be the case.  Does it suggest that a new layer is added every time `setUrl` is invoked?

Comment: Not a new layer, just the same layer is refreshed with the image from new url. Since you didn't included all relevant code in the question, it was impossible to guess where it went wrong.

Comment: If answer helped you solve your problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let other users with similar problem know that problem was resolved.

Comment: Thanks again, TomazicM.  Here's a short html file in Plunker to illustrate the problem.  https://plnkr.co/edit/LFQVaaUOugQ3ZBHn

Comment: If you look at my second comment, you'll read: "First image layers have to be created, **but not added to the map**, then load events have to be created, and **only after that image layers added to the map**."

Comment: Ok, then.  How does one create load events before image layers are added to the map?

Comment: First `Irma = L.imageOverlay(url, bounds);` then `setLoadEvent(Irma);` then `map.addLayer(Irma);`

Comment: I actually tried that earlier but it did not change the results.  So every time you click the reload buttons to invoke `setUrl`, `nLayersLoaded` is increased by 1 (as shown in the console).

Comment: I leave further study of this fenomena to you.

Comment: Ok, TomazicM.  Thanks a lot for your help.